# Django AD integration getting AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application:

Tags: python, django, azure-active-directory

In settings.py i have given these parameters

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (   
   'social.backends.azuread.AzureADOAuth2',  
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_AZUREAD_OAUTH2_KEY = 'xxxxxx-2d74-4d6a-9192-xxxxxxxxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_AZUREAD_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxBpMsu817qnattPRQI9hKLfdQ='    
SOCIAL_AUTH_AZUREAD_TENANT_OAUTH2_TENANT_ID ='xxx50be-xx-4611-bc99-72dafxx'
```

While login into the application it will redirect to Azure login page after enter the credentails am getting

```
AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'xxxxxx-2d74-4d6a-9192-xxxxxxxxx'.
```

In Azure i have given the replay url as  http://ipaddress:8080/login

Please help me Is there any settings need to configure the application ?

Comment: ref this link http://www.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7130
getting same error

Comment: Check the URL in your address bar after you arrive on the AAD login page. Paste the redirect_uri from that here.

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid+profile+user_impersonation&state=YtJvApf3bZ4RD7omgQgC8v8eKifQyXEE&redirect_uri=http://ipaddress:8080/complete/azuread-oauth2/&response_type=code&client_id=50074c83-2d74-4d6a-9192-08c3ec5a0f9d

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if SO does something to the URL when showing it, but the redirect URI is not URL-encoded: `http://ipaddress:8080/complete/azuread-oauth2/`. It should be: `http%3A%2F%2Fipaddress%3A8080%2Fcomplete%2Fazuread-oauth2%2F`.

Comment: Hi juunas 
'social:begin' 'azuread-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }}" This is the redirect path.

Comment: Changed the integration by ref this page,converted the code in Django and working now

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-webapp-graphapi